# jquery регистраиция

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#registerForm').submit(function(e) {

    register();
    e.preventDefault();

});

});

function register()
{
hideshow('loading',1);
error(0);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "register.php",
    data: $('#registerForm').serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg){

        if(parseInt(msg.status)==1)
        {
            window.location=msg.txt;
        }
        else if(parseInt(msg.status)==0)
        {
            error(1,msg.txt);
        }

        hideshow('loading',0);
    }
});

}

function hideshow(el,act)
{
    if(act) $('#'+el).css('visibility','visible');
    else $('#'+el).css('visibility','hidden');
}

function error(act,txt)
{
    hideshow('error_registration',act);
    if(txt) $('#error_registration').html(txt);
}
```

Вот код регистрации на jquery работает почему то в версии 1.3.2 только,помогите что можно сделать что бы работал в веерсии по моложе ?(register.php отсылает ошибку вида    *die('{status:0,txt:"All the fields are required"}');* в div #error_registration ).Пс как можно сделать что когда отправляется запрос экран немного темнел и показывалась картинка loading ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All the fields are required

Видимо значения полей не отправляются, проверьте какие данные приходят в register.php и приходят ли.

> Пс как можно сделать что когда
> отправляется запрос экран немного
> темнел и показывалась картинка loading

Вот две функции http://pastebin.com/PY2eyWBj пользуйтесь на здоровье. Перед отправкой данных вызывайте append_splash(); а по завершении remove_splash();

PS Администрации форума, проблемка небольшая, попытался вставить [Этот код](http://pastebin.com/PY2eyWBj) в текст сообщения, и он начал выполнятся :) Браузер Chromium 20

Answer (score 0):

чтобы работал "в веерсии по моложе" попробуйте заменить:

```
dataType: "json"
```

на

```
dataType: "text json"
```